# setting UIButton font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code for setting up text in a UIButton

```
[self.fullListButton_ setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.newsfeedItem_.newsfeedToSubjects count] - 3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The issue is I can't seem to set the font for this. How do I do so?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the newer version of iOS:

```
UIButton * myButton;
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
```

Or any other font mechanism.

Look here for the UIButton portions:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel

And here for the UIFont stuff:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In your code:

```
self.fullListButton_.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12];
```

or

```
self.fullListButton_.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
```

Comment: @xonegirlz :Make sure that you are not trying to set font for a SystemButton.

Comment: It would be "titleLabel", not "titleLable"