# How to set font on Title of Button Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I am trying to set the font of a title on a button. I read from Apples Documentation on Fonts in Objective C and tried to implement but its not changing the font . I also tried this post... [setting UIButton font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443283/setting-uibutton-font). I got my font from google fonts..."Nunito-Black.tff"

Here is my code below,

```
- (void)addHeaderButton {

    _headerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.headerButton.frame = self.bounds;
    self.headerButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [self.headerButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(51.0/255.0) blue:(102.0/255.0) alpha:(1.0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.headerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Nunito-Black" size:25];
    //[self.headerButton setFont:[UIFont  systemFontOfSize:25]];
    [self.headerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(headerButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.headerButton];
}
```

Comment: Does it work at least for a `UILabel`? Is `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Nunito-Black" size:25];` nil ?

Comment: Have you added your font to the project? Read about [this and other common mistakes here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/). Also, see the list of [included fonts here](http://iosfonts.com/).

Comment: @albertamg yes I did

Comment: @Larme how would it be nil ?

Comment: Because you didn't installed it correctly? Because `Nunito-Black` isn't the postscript name of the font? Is it `nil` then? Because if it is, then the issue is about the importation of the font, else, the issue lies somewhere else. But that would help you and us on where to look.

Comment: @KimRiegel Make sure that your font included in the target and in your Info.plist under the "Fonts provided by application" key. Also take into account that you must specify the *font name*, not the file name.

Comment: does your self.headerButton.frame = self.bounds; gives proper frame to headerButton ?

Comment: @albertamg had to add them to info.plist, thank you for the link I learned a lot!

Comment: @Maddyヅヅ yes, I had to add font name to info.plist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the steps for adding custom fonts into your app.

**Step : 1**

Add your custom fonts to your app bundle and your `Info.plist` with **UIAppFonts** (*Fonts provided by application*) key. It's look like below image

[image]

**Step : 2**

Get the custom added font name using below snippet

[*Objective-C*]

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
        NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
        for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            NSLog(@"--Font name: %@", fontName);
        }
    }
```

[*Swift - 3*]

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames {
            print("\(family)")

            for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
                print("   \(name)")
            }
        }
```

**Step : 3**

Get the name of font from above snippet and after getting the name you can set the font name to your respected element as below

```
self.headerButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Nunito-Black" size:25];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the exact name of font to Info.plist under 'Fonts provided by Application'